# How to read cookie from other browser tab in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a web application that creates a cookie. I also have another web application hosted on a different port. From that application, I would like to read the cookie which is created by the 1st web application. Is this possible? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible due to security reasons. It's against [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia sums this up quite nicely

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie :

The cookie domain and path define the scope of the cookie—they tell the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for the given domain and path. If not specified, they default to the domain and path of the object that was requested.[31] However, there is a difference between a cookie set from foo.com without a domain, and a cookie set with the foo.com domain. In the former case, the cookie will only be sent for requests to foo.com. In the latter case, all sub domains are also included.[32][33] An example of Set-Cookie directives from a website after a user logged in, from a request to docs.foo.com

In short - a cookie can only be accessed from the same domain that created it - or a subdomain of that site. If this weren't the case then it would raise some pretty major security issues